# Wordpress restrict user in back-end to certain pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

In my current Wordpress plugin i have create an admin page where there are two select options. First one is to select a user and second one for `wp_dropdown_pages`. When i select a specific registered user of my site and a page from dropdown than save the option. When the specific user login to back-end he can access only the page that i have selected from my admin menu page. I can restrict that user from other menu page using `remove_menu_page( $menu_slug )`. Now i want that user only to access page that i have selected for him. Other pages will be disappeared/access denied from admin `All pages` menu. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the answer, it will help you.
[Restrict admin access to certain pages for certain users][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/restrict-admin-access-to-certain-pages-for-certain-users

Comment: @Noman it worked as a tricks. Thanks.